# Imports not working in Google App Engine project

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Im working in python to build a webapp using GAE. The project was originally built with out GAE, and it worked just great, then I brought those files into the GAE project, and all of a sudden they don't play so nice anymore. One file land.py has 4 classes representing different land types, and a list of list containing several instances of each one. They are all based off the land class, in the land.py file.

```
class Land():
    def __init__(self):
        self.elevation = 0
        self.neighbors = []
        self.creatures = []
        self.location = (0, 0)
        self.was = None#to keep track of when flooded     
    def __str__(self):
        return("location " + str(self.location) + 
               " elevation " + str(self.elevation) + 
               " neighbors " + str(len(self.neighbors)) + 
               " creatures " + str(x.name for x in self.creatures) + " | ")
    def redefine(self, land):
        self.elevation = land.elevation
        self.neighbors = land.neighbors
        self.creatures = land.creatures
        self.location = land.location
        self.was = land
```

The other class simulation.py imports land, and should be able to use it, but when I try

```
self.map =  Land.landMass(the list of list's)    
for row in self.map: 
        print(row)
```

It will print `'[,,,,,,,][,,,,,,,][,,,,,,,][,,,,,,,]'` it does see that there are objects in there because when I do

```
for i in self.map:
            for x in i:
                output += x.__str__()
```

it prints each land object's proper output. This is a problem because when I want to check

```
for row in self.map:
    for column in row: 
        if isinstance(land, Land.Water):  #or type(land)
```

it first has no clue what land is but it also does know what Land.Water is. I can provide code if you like, but it's hard to figure out exactly where the problem could be. Again, in its own project file it all works but in the GAE project it doesn't. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

print(row) is doing a repr(object) not str(obj)  If you look at the source of the page you will see something like

As for the rest of your code, without knowing the definition of Land it's hard to tell.  Is Land a db/ndb Model ?

Also your title for this question doesn't really have anything to do with the question you have asked.  I don't see any problems with imports.

As to the specific question about "it first has no clue what land is" I assume you are getting a `NameError name 'land' is not defined` , if not please include a bit more detail as to the error.  And if it is the correct error, where are you defining `land` ?

Also this line looks wrong `if isinstance(land, Land.Water): or type(land)`  that would give you a SyntaxError

Comment: No, Land is a regular .py file containing a few classes based off of the Land class, I'll add it above.

Comment: When I try to print str(type(x)) or str(type(Land.Water)) I don't get a nameError, I don't get anything, it just prints nothing.

Comment: Are you looking at the output of a webpage or the appengine logs.  You won't get anything in the log with a print. What sort of request handler are you using.

Comment: I'm checking the output on the webpage. I'm using sim = Simulation(text, generations, lengthOfDay)#.simulate()
...
self.write("<pre>%s</pre>" % sim) where Sim ends up being the str function of Simulation

Comment: Well you can't normally mix print with self.write.  View the source of the page as I mentioned earlier and you will see repr() output for the lists.  You should try and focus your question on one thing. You have a bunch of stuff going on, and I feel you are having trouble with some basic appengine/webapp fundamentals.

Comment: That could very well be the case. First when I say printing I'm not actually calling print, it is mearly the str function being called when sim = Simulation, sorry for that confusion. How do I view the source of the page?

Comment: Well, why did you say "print" and show code using the print statement.  If you want help on SO you need to be concise.  As to viewing the source of a webpage, have you never clicked on the right mouse button when viewing a page, and selected "view Page Source"  - if not I think you have a lot to work out if you want to use appengine on build any web service.